# Parsing a specific content out of a dictionary in a json file

Tags: json, swift, nsjsonserialization

I'm getting the error "Cannot cast value of type dictionary to array" when I run my code. I'm tryna parse from a json file but its not working. Please help.

Here's the json file and i'm specifically tryna print out just the name values:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "2f4628f7ef6dce33d856121f",
      "name": "Top products",
      "description": "This category contains all the top products on"
    },
    {
      "id": "3f4628f7ef6dce33d856121d",
      "name": "Trending products",
      "description": "This category contains all the trending products"
    }
  ],
  "page": 0,
  "size": 2,
  "count": 2,
  "status": 200,
  "isSuccess": true
}
```

```swift
func fetchFrontPageSections() {
    let urlString = APIConstants.baseurl + APIConstants.frontpageSections
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers)

            for dictionary in jsonData as! [[String: AnyObject]] {

                print(dictionary["name"])
            }
        } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

When I print the dictionary I'm getting that whole son file in my console which is fine but Im expecting to get a result like:

name: Top Products

name: Trending Products

Comment: Hi Jide, welcome to the site! You should take a look in the Codable feature of Swift. It's the simplest and quickest way to get started with editing JSON. I would  recommend you get started by watching [the 2017 WWDC video, "What's new in Foundation", starting at 23:44](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/212/?time=1424). After you've watched that, and got a conceptual understanding of the Decodable protocol, you can checkout [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io?share=fuYIyaBiYXChRP4zdwsx), which can automate the tedious process of generating large types for JSON decoding.

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll do that now

Answer (score 0):

In your constant `jsonData` you don't have an array, it's a dictionary as your json file explicitly show it. It contains multiple keys such as `data`, `page`, `size`, ...

You shoud access first the value related to the key `data` that contains an at this point the array of dictionary that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. the main issue is that i've tried accessing that but still not working so i'm guessing i don't exactly know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

Parsing Json in Swift has never been easier since `Codable`. 
here's an Excellent tutorial from the great guys at Ray Wenderlich: https://www.raywenderlich.com/3418439-encoding-and-decoding-in-swift

for your specific problem try this:

```
struct Info: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let description: String
}


struct Dictionary: Decodable {
    let data: [Info]
    let page: Int
    let size: Int
    let count: Int
    let status: Int
    let isSuccess: Bool
}


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dictionary = try decoder.decode(Dictionary.self, from: json)
```